# A value of type 'List<ClienteModel>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RxList<ClienteModel>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RxList'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'RxList'.

Comment: Is there a snippet of code we can look at, where the error occurs? Would be helpful in understanding, thanks!

Comment: Ok i got it resolved thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  List initial = [];
  RxList data= RxList(initial);
```

use like this

```
  List<clientModal> clientmodal = [] ;
  RxList<clientModal> data = RxList(initial as List<clientModal> );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to solve it!

Comment: How to do this for RxList in GetX